# How to format a single field with multiple mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I would like a creative idea to create a multiple-masking component.

My purpose is to have a field that accepts multiple macaras.
Example: A field that accepts the following masks: "999.999.999-99", "99.999.999 / 9999-99"

If I type: "99." The second mask is automatically selected.

If I type: "999." Automatically selected the first mask.

Note that I want to do the following verification:

1. Mask is invalid try with second, third, fourth ... mask until one is possible or otherwise bar user input.
2. If the mask field is larger than the current mask and there is a corresponding mask selected and applied to the mask.

An example of what I intend to do can be found  at:  `A field many possibilities (CPF, CNPJ, Phone):
<input type="text" value="" data-custommask-auto-apply="true" data-custommask-template='["999.999.999-99","99.999.999/9999-99","(99) 9999-9999","(99) 99999-9999"]' />`

[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5gd0xj1b/5/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jouvane/hbz0j7rc/

Comment: Gostaria de uma ideia criativa para criar um componente de múltiplas máscaras.

Meu proposito e ter um campo que aceite múltiplas macaras.
Exemplo: um campo que aceite as seguinte mascaras: "999.999.999-99", "99.999.999/9999-99"